# Django 1.9/Haystack 2.4.1 "Model could not be found for SearchResult"

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

Let me just first say, I have tried the fixes here:

[Haystack says “Model could not be found for SearchResult”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314319/haystack-says-model-could-not-be-found-for-searchresult?s=2|1.7930)

and I'm still getting

```
Model could not be found for SearchResult '<SearchResult: dictionary.termentry (pk=u'10')>'.
```

I'm on Django 1.9 & Haystack 2.4.1 with Whoosh. I've determined that the SearchQuerySet is filtering just fine (when I `print queryset` I get a list of `SearchResult` objects). I didn't touch anything beyond the SearchIndex definitions, so this is out-of-the-box stuff. Just for reference, here's the relevant bits of code:

in search_indexes.py:

```
class TermIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True,use_template=True)
    rendered = indexes.CharField(use_template=True,indexed=False)

    def get_model(self):
        return TermEntry

    def index_queryset(self,using=None):
        """Used when updating index for model"""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

in views.py:

```
def search(request):
    query = ''
    queryset = None
    results = []
    showresults = True

    if request.method == 'GET' and request.GET.get('q'):
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        showresults = True

        query = request.GET.get('q')
        # making sure we got a query
        print query
        queryset = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=AutoQuery(query))
        # checking to see if we got anything in our queryset
        print queryset

        for q in queryset:
            print q
            results.append(q.object)

        # checking to see if we got any results
        print results

    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        showresults = False

    context_dict = {
        'query': query, 
        'results': results,
        'form': form,
        'showresults': showresults,
    }

    return render(request, 'search/search.html', context_dict)
```

I don't know what the fix is here, let alone the problem (I mean, the actual problem; I know I'm getting an error). My settings are all by-the-book, and I've nuked/rebuilt the index probably eighty times. I don't have anything funky or fancy going on with my paths or my data structure, I'm not using anything but defaults for backends and databases and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem with Solr. Found the solution here: [Haystack says “Model could not be found for SearchResult”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314319/haystack-says-model-could-not-be-found-for-searchresult)

Basically, Haystack 2.4.1 uses the outdated call to Django, this was fixed in latest the master.

So I've replaced django-haystack==2.4.1 in my requirements with git+git://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack.git and it started to work.

Comment: I didn't know that the pip install version wasn't the master/latest. Good to know. Now, of course, I've got a completely different problem, but this solved this particular issue!